# Can I import repository from VSTS to VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have been exploring the VSTS APIs and trying to copy a repository from one project to another. I get an error `this remote has never connected`. I tried this via the website too and I get the same error so I am guessing my code is correct.

I wanted to know if anyone has done this before or if someone would be kind enough to try this out on one of their VSTS instances.
If you need the code sample let me know. It isn't much other than the one present [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/zh-cn/docs/integrate/api/git/import-requests#create-a-request-to-import-a-repository).

**Update:**
Here is the code. (Boiled down to a console app)

> Models.cs

```
public class ImportProjectRequest
{
    public Parameters parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Parameters
{
    public Gitsource gitSource { get; set; }
    public string serviceEndpointId { get; set; }
    public bool deleteServiceEndpointAfterImportIsDone { get; set; }
}

public class Gitsource
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class ImportProjectCommand
{
    public Uri baseUri { get; set; }
    public string accessToken { get; set; }
    public string TeamProjectName { get; set; }
    public string CollectionName { get; set; }
    public string RepositoryId { get; set; }
    public ImportProjectRequest RequestObject { get; set; }
}
```

> Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        ImportProjectCommand command = new ImportProjectCommand()
        {
            baseUri = new Uri("https://instance-name.visualstudio.com"),
            accessToken = "<permanent-access-token>",
            CollectionName = "DefaultCollection",
            TeamProjectName = "Test Project 3",
            RepositoryId = "Test Project 3",
            RequestObject = new ImportProjectRequest()
            {
                parameters = new Parameters()
                {
                    gitSource = new Gitsource()
                    {
                        url = "https://instance-name.visualstudio.com/_git/Test%20Project"//Server URL from Extrenal Git configured in the serivces tab of Test Project 3
                    },
                    serviceEndpointId = "0f3c8fd4-38bb-4f0f-95fc-8942dd8f53a3", //Retrieved ID from https://instance-name.visualstudio.com/Test%20Project%203/_apis/distributedtask/serviceendpoints?api-version=3.0-preview.1
                    deleteServiceEndpointAfterImportIsDone = false

                }

            }

        };

        string version = "?api-version=3.0-preview";
        var parameters = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", string.Empty, command.accessToken)));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", parameters);
        var url = string.Format("{0}{1}/{2}/_apis/git/repositories/{3}/importRequests",
            command.baseUri,
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(command.CollectionName) ? "DefaultCollection" : command.CollectionName,
            command.TeamProjectName,
            command.RepositoryId);
        HttpContent result;
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url + version, command.RequestObject).Result)
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            result = response.Content;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**
Thanks to @starain i was able to resolve the error partially. The error was caused because there were spaces in my project and repository name.
The code still doesn't work but I am now able to import repositories via the web portal.

I am now stuck at the error where VSTS gives me a message saying

`Service Endpoint not accessible to user defd6044-4747-4926-9726-4d19fa5d2d26`

*Note : GUID above is the GUID of the service enpoint and not the user.*

My authentication is correct because I succeeded in creating a new service endpoint via the REST API.

Comment: In addition, is there a reason you need to use the APIs to copy the Git repository to a new project? Is there a reason you can't add the new location as a new Git remote and push to it?

Comment: Thanks Scott for the edits. We are building an ALM process in our office. We have tooling in place for that ALM process already and would like to leverage the capabilities of VSTS. Also, a lot of guys aren't comfortable learning a new UI.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you switch to some other hosting service. Is the Git repo the only thing you need to move, or are you also trying to move other information that's only accessible via the API?

Comment: As of now only the git repo but eventually may be pre configure work items etc.

Comment: "I tried this via the website too and I get the same error so I am guessing my code is correct." Do you mean you get the same error when try to import the repository from VSTS web portal? If yes, then this is usually caused by two reasons: 1. The server clone URL is incorrect. 2. The credential you entered is invalid.

Comment: @Eddie Please see update 2. Might clarify where i currently stand.

Comment: @Tanmay Did you add the user to both two projects?

Comment: Yes I did that. I get a 201 from the import request, that is the import was scheduled. Later when i navigate to the git repo on the web portal i receiver the error listed in Update 2

Comment: Then you need to make sure the service point id is correct.

Comment: @Tanmay What's the result if you get service endpoint by that endpoint ID through REST API? (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/endpoints/endpoints#get-a-service-endpoint)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my test, I succeed importing a repository from a VSTS to another VSTS. You can refer to these steps to import repository.

1. Click your name=>Security=>Select Alternate authentication credentials=>Create an alternate authentication credentials
2. Go to target VSTS, click services tab in team project admin page, then click New Service Endpoint=>External Git=>Type Connection Name, Server URL (a git repository in source VSTS), User name and Password (alternate account, step 1)
3. [Get a list of service endpoint](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/endpoints/endpoints#get-a-list-of-service-endpoints) through REST API (XXX) (e.g. https://[target VSTS name].visualstudio.com/[team project]/_apis/distributedtask/serviceendpoints?api-version=3.0-preview.1], after that you could get service endpoint id of that service endpoint (step 2)
4. [Create a request to import a repository](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/import-requests#create-a-request-to-import-a-repository), for example:
   Address(post request): https://[target vsts name].visualstudio.com/[team project]/_apis/git/repositories/[repository name]/importRequests?api-version=3.0-preview

Json:

```
{
  "parameters":
    {
      "gitSource":
        {
          "url": "[git repository address in source VSTS]"
        },
      "serviceEndpointId": "[service endpoint id, step 3]",
      "deleteServiceEndpointAfterImportIsDone": false
    }
  }
```

Note: the repository name and team project name can't contain whitespace.

Comment: I tried the above steps and it didnt work for me. Did you test this on the same VSTS instance? Because that is my scenario.

Comment: @Tanmay It is working fine for me with the same VSTS instance (different team projects), did you add external git service? What's your detail steps?

Comment: My answer was quite long and i had to use pastebin for answering this comment. Can you please look [here](http://pastebin.com/jP91WQYw)

Comment: @Tanmay do you specify api-version? You can share a sample project on the OneDrive.

Comment: I have updated my question with a code sample. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Tanmay I found the reason, the reason is that your source team project name or repository name has whitespace between words. You can try to import a repository from a team project that both names don't contain whitespace and check the result. (I updated my answer with this)

Comment: Wow! So i tried a completely new setup and I've managed to move forward. Now i get an error from the REST API `Service Endpoint not accessible to user defd6044-4747-4926-9726-4d19fa5d2d26` (the guid is service endpoint guid). I tried to see if my auth is correct; tested it with creating a new service endpoint via the REST API. DId you try the same through code? Also, I have succeeded importing the project via the web portal.

Comment: @Tanmay Your code is working for me (I removed collectionname). Did you get that service endpoint with the same personal access token?

Comment: Yes. I created it with the same access token and then copied it from the JSON GET request to `_apis/distributedtask/serviceendpoints`

Comment: @Tanmay Try to create a new service endpoint. (I can reproduce this issue if service endpoint id is incorrect)

Comment: @Starin thanks for your help. I manged to solve it. Your steps were correct. I gave it one more shot with a fresh mind in the morning and stuff worked.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that I was able to import a repository with the very same steps described by starain, the only difference is that I've created the endpoint with API and used PAT token to create endpoint instead of relying on alternate credentials (but this should not change anything)

Everything went good, and the only way to replicate your error

```
Service Endpoint not accessible to user defd6044-4747-4926-9726-4d19fa5d2d26
```

is to specify a wrong id of the endpoint (endpoint that does not exists) or use a wrong token in endpoint definition. This suggests me that there are problems with the endpoint you have created.

The simplest option is to create the endpoint with api with a POST call to 
https://xxxxx.VisualStudio.com/TEAMPROJECT_WITH_TARGET_GIT_REPO/_apis/distributedtask/serviceendpoints?api-version=3.0-preview.1

specifying the Source Repository with url,

```
{
  "name": "TestImport",
  "type": "git",
  "url": "https://yyyyyyyy.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/TargetGitProject/_git/ElasticSearchExamples",
  "authorization": {
    "scheme": "UsernamePassword",
    "parameters": {
      "username": PAT_TOKEN,
      "password": ""
    }
  }
}
```

This will create the endpoint and immediately gives you the ID

```
{
  "data": {},
  "id": "**df12f2e3-7c40-4885-8dbd-310f1781369a**",
  "name": "TestImport",
  "type": "git",
```

This should assure you that you use an id of a valid endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Alkampfer. Tried this morning and it worked for me. Weirdly though i didn't change anything in my code! One of those days probably. Thanks for your help

Comment: This is strange, but I'm glad to know that everything works :).

Comment: I must say i noticed VSTS api go into 3.0-preview.2 mode and then come back to preview.1. Might be the reason, but we will never know :)